# CodePlex import

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm unable to import my [CodePlex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex) project to [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers).

I click "Add CodePlex", it asks for authorization, and then says

> We found the following projects for {"UserName":"Const_me","MemberSince":"10/20/2011 12:52:45 PM"} on CodePlex.

[My project](http://esentserialize.codeplex.com/) is not listed there.

If it matters, I'm using the [Opera web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29).

Comment: Same problem (chrome browser.) I'm the coordinator of the project, not a developer (can't be both). Hope this helps.

Comment: Same here, I'm the coordinator of one project on CodePlex and have the same problem when I try to import my account for my careers profile.

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: When I import codeplex it shows no projects in a list, it imports the first project. After that I have no options and it will not import the second one. I tried to add it manually and it asked me to import it.

Comment: I also experience this.. if it matters I am using Chrome

Comment: I also experience this and im using IE.

Comment: Looks like an API change at CodePlex. We’ll have a fix ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be resolved. Give it another try?

Comment: thanks, it works. Found another bug, BTW, gonna ask a new question..

Comment: Plz take a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159529/201644