# Is this the right place to report Stack Overflow Careers bugs?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

Is this is the right place to report bugs?

Some old answers say "yes".

However, [I've submitted the bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155242/201644) a month ago. Since that time, multiple users were able to confirm the bug in pretty much every browser.

Usually, after I report a bug in some product, they reply something after a while, e.g. "thanks for your feedback, we'll fix it in the next version" or "thanks for your feedback, sorry to inform you the behavior is by design and we're not going to fix it".

However, in this case I've got absolutely no official response.

Is there some bug report form, or maybe e-mail address, that (unlike MSO) is monitored by the site maintainers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow *is* the right place to report bugs, and it's monitored by the developers.

Don't know why you haven't received any feedback after more than a month, generally there's at least a comment from a Stack Exchange employee on the first couple of days after a (serious) bug report have been posted. My guess is that they missed it, it happens sometimes.

You could contact Stack Exchange directly if you want ("contact us" link in the footer), but I've also notified a SE employee through the mod-only chat room to take a look at your bug report and nag the developers about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll use the contact form if nothing will happen with that bug within a few days.

Answer (score 8):

I asked the Careers 2.0 Development team about your issue -- they have seen it and they say they know how to fix it. I'm sure you'll hear from them once the fix is in!