# CodePlex Import 2

Tags: bug, jobs

I'm unable to import my new CodePlex [project](http://turnoffhdd.codeplex.com/) to Careers.

I click "Add CodePlex", it asks for authorization, and then says

> Hmm, we were unable to retrieve your information. Would you like to try again?

I’ve tried adding manually, by clicking “Please enter the URL of your project home page”, however it said

> Please use our CodePlex page (/import/codeplexauth/20877) to add CodePlex projects.

If it matters, I'm running Windows 10 and using MS Edge

Comment: Sorry, but are you really linking us to Wikipedia to know what SO Careers is?

Comment: Just copy-pasted from my old question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155242/codeplex-import